# spring-boot-maven-plugin repackage not including dependancies

Tags: maven, spring-boot, plugins, fatjar

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>com.securebort.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> 

    <name>services</name>
    <description>Cipherworks services exposed to the client applications</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version> 
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <beanstalk.versionLabel>${maven.build.timestamp}</beanstalk.versionLabel>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
                        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
                        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
           <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.cipherworks</groupId>
           <artifactId>cwcommon</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
           <groupId>securebort</groupId>
           <artifactId>datacrypt</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.cwkit</groupId>
           <artifactId>cwkit</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.cipherworks</groupId>
           <artifactId>iam</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>                 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>                         
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>       
              <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version> 
              <configuration>
                 <layout>JAR</layout>
                 <mainClass>com.cipherworks.services.ServicesApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration> 
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
          </plugin>  
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

when i do mvn package, it creates a repackaged jar file. But the repackaged jar does not contain my dependancies cwcommon, datacrypt and cwkit jars. I have checked my local repository and it has all my dependent jar files. For some reason, they are not getting repackaged into the fat jar.

Output of the goal dependency:tree:
I could not copy and paste all the output due to size limitation in stack overflow. I have only copied sections that has my dependencies.

```
....
....
....
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\CipherWorks\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\CipherWorks\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.securebort.services:services:jar:0.0.2: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix dependency from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix dependency to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin from POM com.securebort.services:services:jar:0.0.2
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.securebort.services:services:jar:0.0.2
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [dependency:tree]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building services 0.0.2
....
....
....
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.securebort.services:services:0.0.2
....
....
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.32:provided
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.32:provided
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.32:provided
[DEBUG]    org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:9.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cipherworks:cwcommon:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    securebort:datacrypt:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cwkit:cwkit:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile (version managed from 2.6.2 by org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.4.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile (version managed from 1.7.24 by org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.4.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.5 by com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.6)
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
....
....
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cipherworks:iam:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.396:compile
[DEBUG]          com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dlm:jar:1.11.396:compile
.....
.....
[DEBUG]   (f) outputType = text
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.securebort.services:services:0.0.2 @ C:\git\services\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: com.securebort.services:services:0.0.2 @ C:\git\services\pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@3872bc37
...
...
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.32:provided
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.32:provided
[DEBUG]    org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:9.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cipherworks:cwcommon:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    securebort:datacrypt:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cwkit:cwkit:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile (version managed from 2.6.2 by org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.4.RELEASE)
...
...
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[DEBUG]    com.cipherworks:iam:jar:0.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.396:compile
[DEBUG]          com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dlm:jar:1.11.396:compile
...
...
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.32:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.32:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:9.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.cipherworks:cwcommon:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- securebort:datacrypt:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.cwkit:cwkit:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
...
...
```

My dependencies (cwkit, cwcommon, datacrypt, iam) are showing up in the INFO output. But they are not getting included in fat jar.

Comment: it looks all ok. are you sure its not working? whats the size of the repackaged jar and the original one? spring boot will not extract the jars but add them as archives and adding its own classloader into the manifest. Are the missing dependencies of type jar? or some pom?

Comment: 18938 - Original Jar

Comment: Repackaged jar size 126292504 , original jar size 18938;  All the missing dependent jars in my local repository. How do i check if the dependencies are of type jar or pom?

Comment: well that size looks ok. are all other jars in the uber-jar? only those few are missing? can you lsit the ones in the uber-jar? Just check if the artifactId/groupId of you depenendencies actually point to a jar. And if there is some scope issue maybe? It does not seem you inherit those from somewhere so I don't think thats it. If nothing helps try "-X" to enable debug. Maybe the spring-ppot plugin will log if it skips some jars.

Comment: I enabled debug and I see that my dependencies are listed in this variable. IprojectArtifactMap = { ...... , securebort:datacrypt=securebort:datacrypt:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.cipherworks:iam=com.cipherworks:iam:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.cipherworks:cwcommon=com.cipherworks:cwcommon:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided,...}. So I am guessing Maven is intending to package my jars. But my jars are not found in the repackaged jar.  I have identified the list of missing jar files, but I am unable to determine any pattern among the missing jar files.

Comment: do those jars contain anything? classes or resources? the provided scope of cwcommon will not include the jar. the compile scope should include it.

Comment: I changed the scope to compile and it is not including the jar. Those jars are part of my application and have my application classes. My Spring boot service needs the classes in those jars.

Comment: can you try to remove the <layout>JAR</layout> from the plugin config? maybe that changes a default of some kind

Comment: How have you identified that the repackaged jar does not include some dependencies? Can you share a list of its contents?

Comment: Can you also provide the output from `mvn dependency:tree` and `unzip -l target/*.jar`

Comment: I removed <layout>JAR</layout> and recreated the fat jar. The fat jar is still missing my dependencies.

Comment: Phil Webb, I have added the depencency:tree and the output of the command which searched the fat jar.

Comment: The command you used to search the jar doesn't really tell us very much. Can you please provide a list of the jar's contents as Phil and I have already requested?

Comment: I have added the output of unzip as suggested by Phil. Thanks.

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, I have also searched the web for solution for this issue. I have also gone through the plugin documentation fairly well. I am kind of running out of options. Should i open this issue in git? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's really not enough information to tell why the jars are not being included. The only property that could affect things is `excludes` and it looks like that's not set in your POM.

I'm guessing that you're unable to share the complete project, and you've not been able to replicate the problem in a smaller sample. The only option really left is to debug the plugin yourself. Here's how you can go about that.

#### 1) Checkout the Spring Boot code base at the tagged version that you're using in your POM file:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git
$ cd spring-boot
$ git fetch --tags
$ git checkout v2.0.4.RELEASE
```

#### 2) Import the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `spring-boot-loader-tools` into your favorite IDE.

You should be able to import just that project. It doesn't really matter if it doesn't compile since we just need to start the remote debugger and set into the code.

#### 3) Run your maven build using `mvnDebug`

You'll need to have the full version of Maven installed to do this.

```
$ cd ~/myproject
$ mvnDebug package
```

#### 4) Attach the remote debugger

Maven should output something like this:

```
Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

Head back to your IDE and add a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo.java#L211) before start a remote debugging session on port 8000.

#### 5) Debug

You can now step into the code and see what's going on. You'll specifically want to look [the Repackager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/Repackager.java#L424) to see if libraries are getting written. One possible cause of your problem is that the `isZip` method returns `false`. Check the result of that method and look to see if your libraries definitely valid zip files?

Answer (score 0):

When I added maven.test.skip = true under properties in pom.xml the problem went away. Thanks for the helpful tips.